# Java socket timeout read timeout exeption

Tags: java, linux, tcp, network-programming

I don't understand please explain.

When i got
socket.Timeoit Exception read timeout  How is it work in default setting in JAVA? Where is manage it? I got timeout after 60 sec.
The some information tell this is manage by
socket.setSoTimeout();
Another resources, this parameter manage on OS level.
First question. What value is default of read timeout and where can i set.
Second
has OS (Linux) level setting of tcp/ip relation to this exeption? Which parameters response for that.
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/tcp-timeout

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/bcfsoz?topic=tcpip-timeout-behavior-linux-application-server

Comment: The default read timeout is infinity. You can change it with `Socket.setSoTimeout()`. You cannot change the default in the operating system as far as I am aware: it is always infinity. Your links are about the connect, ACK, and keepalive timeouts. Neither is relevant to read timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

I also don't have actual idea on whats the default socket timeout but according to [JBoss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossremoting/2.5.4/userguide/html/chapter-4-socket-transport.html) its 30 minutes i.e. 1800000 milliseconds. This means that any socket operation that does not complete within 30 minutes will throw a **SocketTimeoutException**.

Yes, as you mentioned you can ovverride the socket timeout as per your requirements by calling `setSoTimeout()` method on socket object.

Eg:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
```

And another thing the system/OS has its own settings that affect how it handles network connections, and these settings are separate from the timeout we set in Java.

Parameter tcp_fin_timeout can influence on tcp timeout exception appearance.?

Comment: I saw this document. Is it mean, OS level setting can involve to appearence exeption read. timeot and can be reason of exeption in JAVA?

Comment: I don't think so. Network issues might affect sometimes if you are calling over network or internet.

Comment: In my case. Network is ok. Some web service does not answer for 60 sec, when its need prepare a lot of data. I can not change code on server and client and see its. I want to understand , why 60 sec read timeout i get, and how change if is it possible. On os level client, vm java setting and so on

Comment: The value of '1800000 milliseconds (30 minutes)' is *what is passed to the `Socket.setSoTimeout()` method. It is therefore *not* the default, until after this action. And it does not refer to 'any socket action', only to reads.